# Validation error smaller than training error in Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition paper

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cross-validation, deep-learning, residual-networks

At one of the examples of Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition  [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf), figure 4, leftmost graph it's said that thin curves denote training error and bold curves validation error.

[image: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf]

Throughout most of the training though, both the thin teal and red lines (training) are higher than the bold ones (validation) in the plain networks. Why is that?

The only moment the training error is lower than validation error is around 50e4 iterations when it spikes downwards. Shouldn't the training error be usually lower?